# Как вывести результат выполнения скрипта из Django в Vue.js?

Tags: django, веб-программирование, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

Есть проект Djano+DjangoRest+Vue.js.

В нём реализовано простейшие приложение для создания заметок, с этим разобрался, запросы к Django отправляются, всё сохраняется и выводится.

Так же есть простая форма, в которую пользователь вводит данные, они должны обрабатываться на стороне сервера скриптом, а результат выполнения скрипта выводиться в Vue, но я не понимаю, как это реализовать. 
Могу ли я через Axios отправить HTTP-запрос к Django, выполнить скрипт, а в качестве ответа получить результат выполнения скрипта и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример использования axios и vue в django:

```
new Vue ({
      el: '#app-info',
      delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
      data () {
        return { this.info: null, }
      },
      methods: {
        get_info: function () {
          axios.get("{% url 'app_info:info-detail' %}")
           .then(response => {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log(response.data); // для понимания ответа сервера
                this.info = response.data.info;
              }
           })
        }
      })
```

Axios нужно использовать в паре с django rest framework. В данном примере выполняется get-запрос для получения объекта класса info. response.data представляет собой JsonResponce, который можно передать в vue (ко ключам взять значения).

На странице:

```
<button v-on:click="get_info">Получить информацию</button>
<p>Полученная информация: [[ info ]]</p>
```

Если потребуется, то поясню остальное.